# Laravel. Как вызвать view()->share() только для администратора?

Tags: php, laravel

На сайте есть блок, скажем, с количеством новых публикаций за последние сутки. Он отображается на всех страницах, поэтому я передаю его в шаблон по `view()->share()`.

Этот блок нужно показывать только администратору. Но сделать это нужно так, чтобы его отображение регулировалось не в шаблоне, а в коде, так как этот запрос довольно энергозатратный (на 500 мс). То есть нужно вообще не готовить данные к выводу для остальных пользователей.

Изначально я это делал в методе `boot` файла `AppServiceProvider.php`, но там не доступен `Auth`, которым можно было бы определить, является ли пользователь администратором.

Я решил перенести эту задачу в новый Middleware. Там `Auth` прекрасно работает, но только на обратном пути, уже после `$response = $next($request);` и перед `return $response;`.

Но в этом месте уже не срабатывают `view()->share()` так как их нужно привязывать к шаблонам до погружения в `$next`.

Собственно вопрос. Как можно всё переделать так, чтобы `view()->share()` работали вместе с проверками по `Auth` и чтобы все работало глобально по всему сайту, а не в определенных контроллерах?

Comment: Можно сделать вполне как вы и сделали через [boot](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#view-composers), и Auth::user() успользовать из композитного класса как в документации, не в статике.

Comment: Композитный класс это то, что через App\Http\View\Composers идет? Если оно, то и вам спасибо, уже нашел решение )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно сделать с помощью ViewComposer. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#view-composers

Создаёте композер, в методе compose делаете нужные проверки и запросы, а потом вызываете из сервис провайдера `Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::composer()`. В качестве аргументов передаёте имя шаблона где надо выводить данные и созданный композер.

Пример

```
// Файл App\Http\Composers\TitleComposer - получение информации о заголовках 25 новейших новостей

namespace App\Http\ViewComposers;

use App\Models\News;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\View\View;

class TitleComposer
{

    public function compose(View $view)
    {
        $titles = null;
        if(Auth::user()->isAdmin())
        {
            $titles = News::select('title')->newest()->take(25)->get();
        }

        $view->with('titles', $titles);
    }
}


// Файл App\Providers\AppServiceProvider

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Http\ViewComposers\TitleComposer;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        View::composer('layouts.news', TitleComposer::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Как-то пропустил этот момент с композером в документации. Я, правда, вообще все упростил до замыкания в буте аппсервиспровайдера:
View::composer('index', function ($view) { ... }); 
чтобы не создавать новый файл для него, и \Auth::user() так тоже прекрасно работает.